# How to manage a bit repository for a multiple-language project

Tags: git

I'm working on a project made up of multiple modules.
Most modules are written in Java, but some are in C++ and Python.
Currently, I have a separate repository for each module and I'm using git submodules to manage them together.

I would like to know what are the best practices in terms of programming languages. Is it advisable to have a repo for a Java programming module and another for a Python one or is it perfectly fine to have them both in the same repository?

What considerations should be taken when setting the repo structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From git perspective, it doesn't matter which language you develop your code.

> Currently I have a separate repository for each module and I'm using git submodules to manage then together.

This is a suitable solution and makes sense since it allows you do to develop independent modules which as you described.

Another solution that is less convenient is to use subtree and have each module in a different branch. `git subtree` manage all the code in a monolithic repository while submodule uses a different repository per module.

---

> What considerations should be taken when setting the repo structure?
>   There are many considerations - here are few which you can consider

1. Does any module has its own life (develop cycle, build cycle, release cycle, etc)
2. What are the relations between the modules? Are they coupled together?
3. Can each module be used alone?
4. Can you convert each module to a microservice and deploy each one separately?
5. Does each repository have its own workflow?
6. Do you need to limit access to the different repostories

So basically it's more like opinion-based considerations

and more....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Each module is self-contained and can run as a micro-service. The modules are decoupled and communicate using queues.